# Padrino: could not find mounted router after mount another project into main project

Tags: ruby, rack, mount, padrino

**issue description :**

there are two project, one is main project, another project is timesheet_app.
and I want to mount timeheet_app to main project.

when access url  `http://localhost:3000/tsheet/base`, it say
 "Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty"

```
Try this:
# in app.rb
class Qiankun::App
  get '/tsheet/base' do
    "Hello World"
  end
end
```

Here is console output

```
 DEBUG - 20/Aug/2014 14:15:22      GET (0.0870s) /tsheet/base - 404 Not Found
 DEVEL - 20/Aug/2014 14:15:22 Reloading application TimesheetApp::App
 DEVEL - 20/Aug/2014 14:15:22 Reloading application TimesheetApp::App
 DEVEL - 20/Aug/2014 14:15:22 Reloading application TimesheetApp::Tsheet
 DEVEL - 20/Aug/2014 14:15:22 Reloading application TimesheetApp::Tsheet
 DEBUG - 20/Aug/2014 14:15:22      GET (0.1120s) /tsheet/__sinatra__/404.png -
04 Not Modified
```

while in timesheet_app self, after run "padrino start", access `http://localhost:3000/base is ok.`.

in main project, check "rake routes", find another projects's url "tsheet/base" is just there.

```
 (:base, :index)      GET    /tsheet/base
```

below is some code related with mount.

**in main project apps.rb**

```
Padrino.mount('TimesheetApp::App', :app_file => TimesheetApp.root('app/app.rb')).to('/time_sheet')
Padrino.mount('TimesheetApp::Tsheet', :app_file => TimesheetApp.root('tsheet/app.rb')).to("/tsheet")
```

**in main project gemfile**

```
   gem 'timesheet_app',:path=>"d:\\IdeaLab\\timesheet_app",:require=>"timesheet_app"
```

**Here is controller code, quite simple**

```
TimesheetApp::Tsheet.controllers :base do
   enable  :reload

  get :index do
   "hello , tsheet!"
  end
end
```

any idea ? maybe a bug in padrino framework?

padrino version 0.12.3

Answer (score 0):

I think the `mount` with `.to('/time_sheet')` confuses me and you and maybe even padrino.

It should make the following adresses available: `http://localhost:3000/time_sheet/tsheet/base` and
`http://localhost:3000/tsheet/` (index).

The apps do not "know" where they are mounted to, that makes it easier for you to define "local" apps and define the controllers without need to change if you include this app somewhere else later.

What makes the thing more difficult to digest then necessary is that you define `get '/tsheet/base` and later mount something as `tsheet`, it also makes it more difficult to talk about. If your question is not answer, please consider renaming first, to make your example more easy to understand and talk about.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix: Please set set :reload, false to your gemified app.

https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/issues/1746